# gwt-style=obf creates invalid css for media queries

Tags: css, gwt

I compile my gwt project with `gwt-style=OBF` and realize that this generates media queries where the space between "and" and "(" is missing.
So out of 
@media screen and ( ... gets
@media screen and(

According to W3C this not ok and also does not work (at least in Chrome and Firefox). Do you have any idea how to generate working CSS and still use `gwt-style=OBF`?

Comment: Is this with a `.gss` or `.css`?

Comment: This is with css

Answer (score 1):

"GWT-CSS" (or "GWT-aware CSS") is limited to CSS 2. If you want CSS 3 you have to use ["GSS"](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideGssVsCss.html).

Answer (score 1):

this post was a mistake by myself. I assumed that obfuscation would cause the problem above. As I learned now it has nothing to do with obfuscation but with minifying the css. We used yui-compressor which has a known bug when it comes to @media and ... So we just need to switch the tool for minifying the css.

Sorry for the mistake